# how can i generate boundary in 2d space from sum of finite vectors.

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry

the setup is that i have only limited number of 2d vectors

$D = ((x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), ...,(x_n, y_n))$

where $0<x_i<1, 0<y_i<1, \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i \leq 1, \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i \leq 1 $

Start from origin `(0, 0)`, you can pick any number of vectors to follow to generate a path, within one path, one vector can only be used exactly once.

The end of the paths are the points we care, and it would form a set of points within the $(0,1) \times(0,1)$ plane, i'm wondering how can i get all the boundary points smartly, without actually generate all the points and then use convex hull algorithm to capture that.

Comment: Perhaps: Sort the vectors angularly about the origin, then add them together in counterclockwise order.

Comment: i'm not sure how would this work, since there is no constrain on how many vectors to be used to form a new vector..

Comment: Sorry to brother you@JosephO'Rourke but does this solution generalize to 3D or even 4d ? If so, what should i sort by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I meant by my comment:

> Perhaps: Sort the vectors angularly about the origin, then add them together in counterclockwise order.

No doubt I am misinterpreting what you are seeking. If so, try to clarify.

---

[image: Vecs]       [image: Sum]

          

<sup>Left: Vectors in 1st quadrant.    Right: Vector sum in ccw angular order.</sup>

---

*Added* after @achillehui clarified the OP's intent:

---

[image: VecsBoth]

          

<sup>Ccw lower path, cw upper path.</sup>

---

*Added 16Sep2019*. Two remarks.

(1) Because of the
commutativity of vector addition, the total sum of the vectors is the same regardless of in which order they are added. See the figure below (based on a different set of $10$ vectors).

(2) Suppose a prefix of the lower envelope is formed
by the first $k$ vectors ccw. If you next add any vector
different from the $(k+1)$-st vector ccw, then you will
penetrate into the interior of the lower hull, left of what would be obtained by adding the $(k+1)$-st vector ccw. This is nearly a proof by induction.

---

[image: RandPaths]

          

<sup>Several random permutation sums (green): Always sum to same point.</sup>

---

Comment: I think you also need to add them together in clockwise order. When you have $n$ vectors, I believe the outliner contains $2n$ sides. the lower $n$ of them comes from adding them counterclockwisely, the upper $n$ comes from adding them clockwisely.

Comment: @achillehui: Ah, I see now what the OP is asking: the hull of *all possible paths* formed by these vectors.

Comment: yes, that is what i mean..so there is $n!$ possible paths, their ends would form a cloud, and i only care about the boundary points. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @achillehui why is that? it feels very correct, but why?

Comment: @pengyu I'm thinking in terms of a hypercube. The axes of that hypercube get projected to the vectors you have and what you want is the boundary of the projected image of that hypercube. The projected image will be a convex polygon in the plane. We know that for a convex polygon, the angles between an edge and $x$-axis will be monotonically increasing as you transverse across the boundary. 
Since each edge in the image comes from one of your vectors, if we sort your vectors and add them counterclockwisely, one get one half of the boundary

Comment: (the part joining the zero-vector to the sum of all vectors). If we sort the vectors and add them clockwisely, one get another half of the boundary (the part joining the sum of all vectors back to the zero-vector). BTW, this argument is just handwaving, nothing rigorous.

Comment: ah..i think i get it, because i can only use one vector exact once, and because we already sorted the vectors, this would push the points to the boundary. but would it be possible to have some elegant proof? thanks a lot!

Comment: @achillehui  i have a related question, which might be more interesting than this one [partial sum of permutation based vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356540/boundary-of-partial-sum-of-k-permutation-of-2d-vectors-in-2d-space)

Comment: @achillehui does your solution generalize to 3D or 4d points? If so what should I sort with ...

Comment: @pengyu: I think what you are seeking in arbitrary dimension $d$ is the [zonotope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonohedron#Zonotopes) formed as the Minkowski sum of your vectors.

Comment: @pengyu No idea... Joseph is a true geometer, I'm just an amateur ;-p

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke thanks for the added remarks! it might be too much, but what if we only have limited number of permutation based on some data source. is there any clever way to find the boundary? in your remark example, find the boundary of green lines.

Comment: and to fill more context to the problem, i was actually trying to find a maximum over a convex function defined on the grid which is constructed by some permutation partial sum of the vectors. and since the maximum is going to be in the boundary, that's why i care a lot of the boundary. $f(x, y)=\frac{(x-y)^2}{y*(1-y)}$ and $0<x<1, 0<y<1$.

Comment: @pengyu: I think now your questions/issues are too specific to your particular circumstance to reply with a general answer.